# PHP - curlopt_ssl_verifypeer false not working

Tags: php, ssl, curl

When I execute this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, curlOPT_URL, "https://www.extern.com/extern/v/fragebogenweg.php?file=412954715521130");
curl_setopt($ch, curlOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, curlOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, curlOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

`https://www.extern.com/extern/v/fragebogenweg.php`:

```
$requestfrom = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_HOST);

if($requestfrom == 'www.bla.com')
{
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.bla.com");
}
elseif($requestfrom == 'bla.com')
{
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://bla.com");
}

unlink('fragebogen/' . $_GET['file'] . '.json');
```

It's not working, it worked before SSL was installed but now not any more that's why I added

```
curl_setopt($ch, curlOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, curlOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

but it's not helping

**UPDATE**

I get this in chrome console:

```
A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
service-worker.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in the constants:

- curlOPT_URL
- curlOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST
- curlOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER
- curlOPT_HEADER

It appears to be case sensitive; try this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.extern.com/extern/v/fragebogenweg.php?file=412954715521130");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($result);
```